# Assembly Language button function

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

This is my code:

```
ORG 0100H    
    SETB P1.0
DONGU1: 
    JB P1.0,DONGU1
     MOV R4,#0FFH
BASLANGIC:
    MOV DPTR,#NUM
        MOV A,#00H
    MOVC A,@A+DPTR
    MOV P3,#02H
    MOV P2,A
    ACALL GECIKME   

    MOV A,#01H
    MOVC A, @A+DPTR
    MOV P3,#08H
    MOV P2,A
    ACALL GECIKME

    MOV A,#02H
    MOVC A, @ A+DPTR
    MOV P3,#04H
    MOV P2,A
    ACALL GECIKME   

    MOV A,#03H
    MOVC A, @A+DPTR
    MOV P3,#01H
    MOV P2,A
    ACALL GECIKME
    DJNZ R4,BASLANGIC   

     MOV P2,#00H
     ACALL GECIKME1 
     SJMP BASLANGIC
GECIKME1:
     MOV R7,#100D
     MOV TMOD,#01H
     L2:MOV TH0,#0DBH
     MOV TL0,#0FFH
     SETB TCON.4
     L3:JNB TCON.5,L3
     CLR TCON.4
     CLR TCON.5
     DJNZ R7,L2
     RET
GECIKME:
    MOV R0, #200
    DJNZ R0, $
    RET
ORG 0000H
NUM:    DB  58H,6H,7CH,75H
END
```

I would like to add the switch on-off function to my button. When I press the button it should display characters, and when I releas the button, it has to stop.

Currently, it's working just start displaying.
Thank you for suggestions and help.

I just uploaded it to see how it works.

I'm using an [AT89C51RC2](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/AT89C51RC2) and everything works well, except for the off-function for the button.

Comment: Would you mind to translate your labels, please? And while you're at it, some comments what you are doing would help us help you. -- And please, use the correct way to show images directly, not a link.

Comment: Thank you so much, its solved :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you entered `BASLANGIC` you never test P1.0 again.

```
ORG 0100H    
    SETB P1.0
DONGU1: ;Wait for button down
    JB P1.0,DONGU1
     MOV R4,#0FFH
BASLANGIC:
    ... activate LEDs ...
    ... turn LEDs off ...
    SJMP DONGU1 ; and not BASLANGIC
```